# No matching handler found for Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::to("user/login")

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, mockery

How do i go about mocking facades with arguments in laravel 4? For instance, i'm trying to test my user controller and in my 'login' method.

my controller method

```
public function login(){

    $this->beforeFilter('guest');

    $creds = array(
        'email'    => Input::get('email'),
        'password' => Input::get('password'),
    );

    if(Auth::attempt($creds, true)){
        return "successful";
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('user/login')->with('error', true);
    }
}
```

the redirect test that doesn't work

```
    public function testPostLogin(){

        Redirect::shouldReceive('to')->once()->with('error', true);

        $response = $this->action('POST', 'UserController@login');

        $this->assertRedirectedTo('user/login');

    }
```

I'm getting the following exception. I don't know how to inject the 'user/login' parameter into the Redirect mock

> Mockery\Exception\NoMatchingExpectationException : No matching handler found for Illuminate\Routing\Redirector::to("user/login")

Answer (score 10):

In theory you can just mock your `Auth` class.

Try this:

```
Auth::shouldReceive('attempt')->once()->andReturn(true);
```